# django displaying posts and comments

Tags: python, django

this is models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def write(self):
        self.date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('humorge.post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def add_coment(self):
        self.date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

and this is views.py

```
def mainpage(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def post(request):
    datas = Post.objects.order_by('-date')
    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'datas': datas, 'comments': comments})
```

and this is template

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block main %}
<div class="container">
  {% for data in datas %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m7">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="#">
            <span class="card-title">{{ data.title }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>{{ data.content }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <p>{{ data.date }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            {% for comment in comments %}
              {% if comment.post == data.title %}
                {{ comment.date }}<br>
                <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
                <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
              {% endif %}
            {% empty %}
              <p>There is no comments</p>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% empty %}
    <p>there is no posts</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to display posts and comments

when I try to have two posts and each post has one comments

it shows like each posts has two comments

so I added `{% if comment.post == data.title %}` in the template

but it shows nothing

I tried to find answers on google, youtube, some tutorial page....

but what I found was just how to add comments on posts..

or displaying post and comment but actually one post one comment

Comment: I suggest you to not iterate in this way through your comments in your template, because is really a performance issue. For every post in your database, you are refetching and re-loop through all the comments that you have stored. The solution of @VaibhavVishal is better for performances. Also use `Post.objects.order_by('-date').prefetch_related('comments')` increase the performance https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to query list of comments in you views, you need just posts:

```
def post(request):
    datas = Post.objects.order_by('-date')
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'datas': datas})
```

And in template you can then do something like this:

```
{% block main %}
<div class="container">
  {% for data in datas %}
    ...
      <div class="card-action">
        {% for comment in data.comments.all %}  // Gives list of all comments for the current post ie. data
            {{ comment.date }}<br>
            <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
            <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
        {% empty %}
          <p>There is no comments</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      {% empty %}
      <p>there is no posts</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  ...
{% endblock %}
```

Btw the thing that's wrong with the if condition in your template is that you are doing `{% if comment.post == data.title %}` but `commpent.post` is an object of model `Post` and `post.title` is string, so they are never equal. What you need to do is `{% if comment.post == data %}` or `{% if comment.post.title == data.title %}`

Comment: where 'comment_set' comes from?

Comment: I tried your code, but it shows 'there is no posts'

Comment: Don't copy paste my code, I didn't write the whole html(see the `...`), you need to just replace `{% for comment in comments %}` with `{% for comment in data.comments.all %}`. You should use `comments` instead of `comment_set`, because in you `Comment` model you have related name `comments` for Foreign Key `post`. If you don't specify a related name then it's `comment_set` by default.

Comment: @MINSIK (Instead of adding this same answer all over again I am adding a comment below). In your Comment model you have `post = models.ForeignKey('humorge.post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')` which means you are adding relation with `post` model in `humorge` app. If your current application name is `humorge`, then change this, `post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')`. After this follow this answer. To refer the django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: yeah thanks for pointing this out, @MINSIK you should use just `Post` or `'humorage.Post'`(uppercase P) or `'Post'`.

Answer (score 0):

In your post view, instead of:

```py
comment = Comment.objects.all()
```

which will fetch all the comments irrespective of the post it belongs to,

do this:

```py
comment = datas.comments.all()
```

where the 'comments' is the related_name declared in the post field of the Comment model.